# Get the lowest year from LINQ query results

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to find the earliest year from a group of rows returned by a LINQ query. The ActivationDate is stored as a datetime value in the DB.

I know that I can make a separate query to get just the date, but I would rather use the results from the existing query, as it is used for several other things.

```
IEnumerable<MonitoringPanel> panels = from rows in db.MonitoringPanels
                                      where rows.DealerEntity == dealerIDint
                                      select rows;
```

However this keeps throwing an error:

```
var testDate = panels.Min().ActivationDate;
```

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code.
```

It will throw an error even if I try to select the lowest PanelNumner (stored as an int), but the following does work:

```
var testDate = panels.FirstOrDefault().ActivationDate;
```

**Solution**

```
        DateTime testDate = (DateTime)panels.Min( thing => thing.ActivationDate);
        int lowYear = testDate.Year;
```

Comment: Welcom, Mason. It seems you forgot to mention the actual error message?

Comment: Please provide the error message. Initially though, you're using `Min` on the things rather than querying the dates of the things in the first instance (instead should be something like `panels.Min(thing => thing.ActivationDate).ActivationDate;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the Enumerable is of a perimative type you need to add a lambda expression to tell it what property of the class to use. Try

```
var testDate = panels.Min(x => x.ActivationDate);
```

Comment: Min will return `DateTime` (`TResult`). That won't compile ;)

Comment: Cheers dave. I'd normally go with the ordering approach as suggested by James so not used to the workings on `Min`.

Comment: Thank you, that got the result I was looking for `DateTime testDate = (DateTime)panels.Min(thing => thing.ActivationDate); int lowYear = testDate.Year;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tell the `Min()` method what to look for the Minimum of. Which field is the Minimum.

```
var testDate = panels.Min(panel => panel.ActivationDate);
```